# Where/how to store application defined properties about a (SQLite3) database in the database?

Tags: python, database, sqlite

So I have one or more databases with various tables of data.

I need to store some database specific properties. 
E.g. country of scraped website (the website has multiple countries).

What is the best way of doing this? I think it would be best to keep the properties in the database but (SQLite3) is the only way to have another table? (ID, Key, Value) However value may need to be string/text, integer, float/real. To get round this would I just convert them all to string with something like json.dumps/loads
Or this there a better way?

Thanks

Comment: Is the added metadata  likely to change much? Do you really need arbitrary key-value pairs, or would a pre-defined row with columns be enough?

Comment: Once added they are unlikely to change but maybe added at anytime.

Comment: You can update the schema to add columns.

Comment: What advantage does doing it through columns over rows have? As it just seam to make more sense to me to do it through rows. Thanks

Comment: Each column can have a SQL type associated with it, so you get the right Python type automatically.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I'll do that. So you would have 1 row with all the values in their respective columns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, it sounds like you wish you had something like a dictionary associated with a database  where you could store key-value information about how your application interacts with the database.
There are a number of approaches to this; I'd recommend picking the one that works best for your application.

First, assuming you know the keys   that you will use, a simple approach is to create a table that will have at most one row in it:

```
create table properties( country_of_website varchar(2) not null, time_downloaded timestamp not null);
```

I didn't include an id column.  Depending on your ORM model, you may need one.  You will need to make sure that the table never has more than one row.  This approach is nice because you rely on the database's typing.  As has  been pointed out sqlite uses dynamic typing, but you may use another database some day.  This approach works well if you have a small number of properties and you know what they are ahead of time.

On the other end of the spectrum you can do something like

```
create table properties(key varchar(20) primary key, value varchar(256));
```

There you have a table that contains a key and a string representation of the value.  The advantage is that it is fairly dynamic.  The disadvantage is that you will be using the string representation of the property.  That's not much of a disadvantage for sqlite though, but with other databases you can lose the advantage of strong typing to detect programming errors.

A third approach is to have a table per type.

```
create table float_properties(key varchar(20) primary key, value float not null);
```

And also create a string_properties table etc.  I recommend against this approach with sqlite because of the dynamic typing.  This third approach is the most complex and I'd only use it if I needed strong typing and couldn't use the first approach.

Answer (score 0):

SQLite uses [dynamic typing](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html), so you can just store the property values directly in a column.

Comment: Using SQL types per column does give you the right Python type automatically.